# How to create a custom field containing a VideoControl and an image?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, camera, blackberry-jde

Here is my problem : I would like to create a specific component with the camera and an image representing a target overlaying the VideoControl's view.

First I would like to display the camera in a MainScreen with a TitleBar.

Here is my code :

```
 public class ScanScreen extends MainScreen {
private ScanScreen() 
    {
        super();

        this.vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_VCENTER);

        this.controller = new ScanController(this);
        //Initialize the player.
        try
        {
            this.player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?encoding=jpeg&width=1024&height=768");
            this.player.realize();
            this.player.prefetch();
            this.videoControl = (VideoControl) this.player.getControl("VideoControl");

            if(this.videoControl != null)
            {
                // Initialize the field where the content of the camera shall be displayed.
                Field videoField = (Field) this.videoControl.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");

                // Display the video control.
                this.videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
                this.videoControl.setVisible(true);

                // Start the player.
                this.player.start();

                // Add the video field to the main screen.
                if(videoField != null)
                {
                    this.vfm.add(videoField);
                }
                else
                {
                    LabelField sorry = new LabelField("Sorry, we cannot use camera right now.");
                    this.vfm.add(sorry);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Dialog.alert(e.toString());
        }

        // TODO : the camera is hiding the title bar
        this.setTitle("Title");
        this.add(this.vfm);
    }
}
```

The first problem is that the view of the VideoContol is hiding my title bar. How can I fix that ?

The second thing : I have a specific rectangular image representing a target with transparency which I would like to displaying over the view of the VideoControl.

I first tried to create a new class extending Field returning the dimensions of this image and make the image displayed in the paint method (this class is "mypackage.CameraField"). Then I tried to instantiate my VideoField with the name of my new class "mypackage.CameraField" in the initDisplayMode ; but the created videoField is null.

So, is there a solution to create that kind of behaviour ? I am thinking about the native application "Video Camera" in the "Multimedia" folder that displays a VideoControl in a specific area of the screen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that is not possible to customize the VideoControl in any way. We must use it in fullscreen and cannot display anything on it.